# EFCore FirstOrDefault InvalidFormatException for null DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, datetime, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core(version 1.1.1.0) in my project and it is connecting to a SQLite database. I have a database table that contains a date and time value, which in SQLite is represented as a `text` data type and in my EF object, it is a `DateTime`.

This value is not supposed to be null but I have production users who apparently have a null value for this property. So, whenever my application queries this table using `FirstOrDefault`, it throws an `InvalidFormatException` stating that "The string was not a valid DateTime."

I want to be able to get my results back and, if the date value is null, I want to set it to a value and update that row in the SQLite database.

How, in EF Core, can I retrieve the row without throwing the `InvalidFormatException`? I've tried setting the `DateTime` to nullable by both doing `DateTime?` and `Nullable<DateTime>` but neither approach appears to work.

This is a WPF application running against .NET 4.6, if that makes any difference

My object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string error_description { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }

    public DateTime expirationDate { get; set; } // the offending property
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance to check this behavior with ef core 2.0? There have been a lot of fixes related to problems like this in recent versions of ef core...

Comment: A quick scan of the release notes after 1.1.1.0 for "dateTime" or "SQLite" didn't yield anything that stood out to me as a potential fix for this. The only thing I'm wondering is if I have to perform a migration in order for the changes to the model object to fully take effect? Upgrading to 2.0 is an option but I'd rather not pull that trigger unless I have hard evidence that it's a bug in my current EF framework version

Comment: According to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10027 this is fixed in 2.0

Comment: Hmm, that specifically calls out UWP and I'm running a WPF application. I saw this yesterday but it didn't seem close enough to my issue. The OP says that the value 01/01/0001 is being saved but in my case, no value is being saved, it's just an empty string in the DB. If I have to upgrade to 2.0 I suppose it's not the end of the world, was just hoping there would be a less drastic change to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `DateTime?` didn't work, I don't think `NULL`s are your issue. There must be some values that are neither `NULL` nor a proper `DateTime` string.

You could try mapping the column to `string` to find the offending values.

```
var badObjects =
    dbContext.MyObjects.Where(
        o =>
        {
            DateTime value;
            return !DateTime.TryParse(o.expirationDate, out value);
        });
```

Comment: While this didn't exactly work for me, it did lead me to just changing my data type to a string and then casting it to a date time where necessary. Since SQLite stores dates as text, I don't think a migration will be necessary but I may be wrong.